# Question about a part of a proof

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am reading a proof concerning continuity of composite functions. I came across the following in a particular proof.

> Taking $\epsilon=1$ in the definition of continuity, there exists $\delta_{2} \gt 0$ such that if $\left | x - c \right |$ $ \lt \delta_{2}$, then $\left | g(x) - g(c) \right | \lt 1$. Hence $\left | g(x) \right | \lt \left | g(c) \right | + 1$.

I am trying to understand the last sentence.

---

**Attempt**

We have  $\left | g(x) - g(c) \right | \lt 1$, thus using reverse inequality triangle, we have

$$ \left |\left | g(x) \right| - \left | g(c) \right| \right| \leq \left | g(x) - g(c) \right | \lt 1,$$

hence $$ \left |\left | g(x) \right| - \left | g(c) \right| \right| \lt 1 \Rightarrow \left (\left | g(x) \right| - \left | g(c) \right| \right)^{2} \lt 1.$$

Now, taking the root of both sides and rearranging, we have

$$ \left | g(x) \right| - \left | g(c) \right| \lt 1 \Rightarrow \left | g(x) \right | \lt \left | g(c) \right | + 1.$$

---

**Question**

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope your attempt is not correct, as you are not allowed to take the square root on both sides (The Problem is, that your expression inside the parenthesis could be negative, hence you root is not well defined). The proof is much easier.
$$|g(x)-g(c)|> |g(x)|-|g(c)|$$
with the triangle inequality and hence
$$ 1> |g(x)-g(c)|>|g(x)|-|g(c)|$$
hence
$$1+|g(c)|>|g(x)|$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Are you THE Euler????